# Struggling with the integral of $\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)^3 \mathrm{d}$t

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics

I'm doing a physics problem in which I need to find the energy dissipated from air resistance. The straightforward equation which could be solved is
$$\Delta E = k\int_0^T \left(\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t}\right)^3\text{d}t$$
And this comes from solving
$$\ddot{x} = -G\frac{M}{x^2} + k\dot{x}^2 = F_{\text{gravity}} + F_{\text{friction}}$$
Where
$$\Delta E = \frac{1}{2}\left(\dot{x}(T)^2 - \dot{x}(0)^2\right) - GM\left(\frac{1}{x(T)} - \frac{1}{x(0)}\right)$$

I know I can simplify the integral slightly to

$$\Delta E = \int_{x(0)}^{x(T)} \left(\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t}\right)^2\text{d}x$$
But I feel like this just changes the problem, doesn't help it.

I am also told that the frictional component provides a small perturbation to the gravitational component. I have no idea how this could help, but perhaps someone else does.

Comment: I hope you ensure that $\dot x>0$, else the friction term has to be $k|\dot x|\dot x$. It is energy dissipation all the time, regardless of the sign of $\dot x$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you, I'll correct that.

Comment: You're certainly not going to evaluate that integral (and your second version of it makes no sense, by the way) without knowing what $dx/dt$ is. There has to be a different conceptual approach.

Comment: For the perturbation, either $\dot x$ is small, or $k$. In both cases, you could then expand the solution in a perturbation series in powers of $k$. // What exactly is the question you are asking? There is no symbolic solution to this equation, the integral can not be simplified, and the perturbation is only valid for small time steps, free fall without friction does not have a final velocity.

Comment: Have you tried applying two times integration by parts in your second integral?

Comment: Something is off with your differential equation; it is dimensionally incorrect.